# Добавить города в выпадающий список с БД

Tags: javascript

В базе данных хранится некая информация о товаре, в том числе локация (город, страна). На сайте хочу сделать возможность сортировать товар по городам и странам, чтобы человек мог выбрать из выподающего списка (из имеющихся городов, стран). Т.е задача, добавить в выподающий список, имеющиеся города и страны

Моя попытка:

```
    <label for="country_name"></label><input class="onchange" id="country_name" name="country_name" type="text" list="country"  placeholder="Страна" />
<datalist id="country">
</datalist>


  data = {action:'get_data'};
  $.post('inc/core.php', data, function(response){
  obj = JSON.parse(response);
     $.each(obj, function(key, value){
     var country = value['country'];
     var city = value['city'];
      if(!$('#country option').val()){
        $('#country').append('<option value='+country+'>'+country+'</option>'); 
      }else{
         $('#country option').each(function(){
           if( ($(this).val() != country) ){
               $('#country').append('<option value='+country+'>'+country+'</option>'); 
                            }

                        })
                    }
});
```

Дело в том, что города дублируются. Как можно правильно проверить на повторяющиеся названия и в случае повтора, не добавлять?

Comment: `выпадающий` от слова падать. Не через `о`. А по теме, города дублируются в базе? или каким образом у вас появляется 2 города в селекте?

Comment: Может проще тогда добавить в выборку `select distinct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если города выбираются из базы, то почему бы не сделать distinct в запросе?

Comment: Кроме городов и стран, с базы данных берется и другая инфа, которая  может повторятся!

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан, предлагаю пробросить отдельный маршрут апи у себя для того, чтобы получать нормальный список городов. На клиенте, конечно, можно все проверить на повторения, но это не очень красиво.

Comment: @АлександрРейдзан тогда проверяйте есть ли город в селекте, а лучше, сначала сгенерируйте массив городов с проверкой внутри типа `array.indexOf(country) === -1 { array.push(country);}` и потом уже вставьте опции в селект